Trouble with AR Android Painting App with hand tracking
i was trying to make an ar painting app for school but I'm struggling on the steps needed to actually do the task as i am new to android studio and the videos i see on youtube aren't helping me much
Ive tried using android studio and ar core but end up with a huge amounts of errors and warnings and im getting confused on what step to take or if i should try a different approach

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
